# Is there a way in Python to find out where a module is imported from?

Tags: python

Inside a module, can I find out which module imported it ? I want some dynamic behavior depending on the importer's module name. Is that doable in python?

eg:

In my module, I have a class defined

```
MyClass(MyParent)
```

where I want `MyClass` to inherit `MyParent2` if `MyClass` is imported by a specific set of modules.

Comment: How do you plan on controlling if "MyParent2" is a valid class to be extended from? Isn't this introducing a circular dependency? Perhaps this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: "I want some dynamic behavior depending on the importer's module name." The importer's name is not passed along to the import process. There are ways to hook into the process (and *maybe* you could use `inspect` to find the importing module on the stack *somehow*), but certainly not after the fact. The importing module is supposed to be in control of what happens at import time, not the imported module. I can't understand what *practical problem you hope to solve* this way. Could you give a simple example?

Comment: If you want to be able to configure the base class that someone else's class uses, then inheritance smells like the wrong tool; consider using composition (and delegation) instead. How can I coherently say that `MyClass` might be a kind of `MyParent` (and *not* a kind of `MyParent2`) in some cases, but the opposite in other cases? That violates all kinds of basic OO principles.